# What does ADE20k (the scene segmentation benchmark) stand for?

Tags: dataset, computer-vision, image-segmentation

ADE20k is a scene segmentation dataset created by MIT. It is a common benchmark for localization tasks in computer vision research. I cannot find anywhere what the name stands for!

This information isn't presented on their [website](http://sceneparsing.csail.mit.edu/) their  [github](https://github.com/CSAILVision/semantic-segmentation-pytorch) or their [paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bzhou/publication/scene-parse-camera-ready.pdf). Please answer if you know.

Answer (score 1):

20K is a reference to there being roughly 20,000 images in the dataset (although the number of images seems to have been increased after the initial release).

According to a [zhihu post](https://www.zhihu.com/question/390783647/answer/1226097849) from the first author, ADE are the first 3 letters of the name Adela Barriuso, who single handedly annotated the entire dataset. I came across a quite interesting "[Notes on image annotation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.3448.pdf)" written by Adela.

Image of the annotation process.
[image]